# JCrop Problem  with asp.net masterpage

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, jcrop

I have a MasterPage,defaultPage and Cropper page and I am able to use JCrop when I have only default.aspx page and not master page and the cropper page.

Problem:When I have am having masterpage then I am unable to use the Jcrop as it is not showing the Image Cropper rectangle.

Any help will be appreciated!

Here is my code:

Head part of Master Page:

```
 <link href="css/jquery.Jcrop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.Jcrop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.color.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Body Part of MasterPage:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is my Cropper.aspx code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlUpload" runat="server">
  <asp:FileUpload ID="Upload" runat="server" />
  <br />
  <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" Text="Upload" />
  <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Visible="false" />
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlCrop" runat="server" Visible="false">
  <asp:Image ID="imgCrop" runat="server" />
  <br />
  <asp:HiddenField ID="X" runat="server" />
  <asp:HiddenField ID="Y" runat="server" />
  <asp:HiddenField ID="W" runat="server" />
  <asp:HiddenField ID="H" runat="server" />
  <asp:Button ID="btnCrop" runat="server" Text="Crop" OnClick="btnCrop_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlCropped" runat="server" Visible="false">
  <asp:Image ID="imgCropped" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript error ?

Comment: Nothing I am able to upload the image and Unable to crop it as the cropper is not showing up.

Comment: When you initialize jCrop after uploaded the image ? For example, `jQuery('#image_to_crop').jCrop({});`

Comment: Yes I did that too appending in the body but didn't work.

Comment: Can you paste the generated code after the IIS done is work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution at last and it's a simple one to add in the code for server control.

Here is the code I modified:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#<%= imgCrop.ClientID %>').Jcrop({
            onSelect: storeCoords
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You include jCrop two times

```
<script src="js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.Jcrop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Only one is necessary !

Comment: No,Not working actually there are two .js files with the zip file attached.And I thought bot are needed and included.

Comment: Both files are the same, expect that the .min.js is minified one. (without spaces, return, etc..)

Comment: OK but I am breaking my head to solve this prob.I can't understand why this is happening might be I forogot the main basic thing.It's working with the normal .aspx page but not with the master page.

Comment: I'm not APS.NET, but the MasterPage.Default, is not only a template used the .aspx pages ?

Comment: Yes but when we iclude any page we select it iclude with the master page by default.And I am not getting any error at present.